# Converting all data in a Varchar column to a date format

Tags: sql, date, datetime, phpmyadmin, varchar

I'm working on a table with a column, 'Expiry Date', as a varchar with all data formatted as DD/MM/YYYY.

The creator of the table has used the wrong type for this expiry date column and now the client needs to filter and show all records before and after the current date as the time. This means the type needs to be changed to date or datetime type to be able to use the CURDATE() function.

However, the current format of the values does not satisfy and wont allow the type to change unless the format is changed to YYYY-MM-DD (or similar).

Is there any way to mass format the values in this column and this column alone as there are thousands of entries and formatting one by one would be extremely time consuming.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that you are using MySQL.

Perhaps the simplest method is to add a generated column that is a date:

```
alter table t add column expiry_date_date as
    (str_to_date(expiry_date, '%d/%m/%Y'));
```

You can also fix the data:

```
update t
    set expiry_date = str_to_date(expiry_date, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

This will implicitly convert the result of `str_to_date()` to a date, which will be in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

More importantly, you can then do:

```
alter table t modify column expiry_date date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd8d7758bbd77cb026db011975474772) is a db<>fiddle.

You can do similar operations in other databases, but the exact code is a bit different.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, i upvoted the previous answer as it was along the lines of what i was thinking initially but after your solution i see why i shouldn't have as it was not appropriate for a date change.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an update on that column, but before doing it I suggest you to check if the result is what you want.

```
select replace(expiry_date, '/', '-') new_expiry_date
  from table_name
```

If this returns the results you want you can run the following update:

```
update table_name
   set expiry_date = replace(expiry_date, '/', '-')
```

Of course you will need to replace `expiry_date` and `table_name` with the names of your column and table.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Mucio. I had thought about this and tried this method by manually editing the first entry, however, the format still requires the year to be followed by the month and then the day.

What it currently is = DD-MM-YYYY

What it needs to be to satisfy the date type format = YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: I understand the answer, but merely replacing slashes with hyphen does not make the column a date.  How did this get upvoted?

Comment: yes, sorry, I missed that, I didn't see that they started with the day :)